# Why does following $\sqrt{x^2} = \lvert x\rvert$ appear to give an extra solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

$$a=4$$
$$a^2=16$$
$$\sqrt{a^2}=\sqrt{16}$$
$$|a|=4$$
$$a=\pm4$$
Why does it appear as though $a$ can equal $-4$, at the end, even though it was only positive $4$ at the beginning?

Comment: when you square the expression you introduce additional solutions.  This is always a risk and you should be aware it every time you square both sides of an equation.

Comment: Square is not a bijective function. Consequently, extraneous answers may be introduced.

Comment: As @DougM mentioned. Every time you use a function that is not one-to-one on both sides of an expression, you can introduce two values which map to the same point. These then may give new 'solutions'.

Comment: Are you claiming any logical relation between the five equations you wrote down?

Comment: While $a=4$ implies $a^2=16$, it is not true that $a^2=16$ implies $a=4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to debug such things is to plug $a=-4$ into each of your equations to find the point where it *first* became true for the unwanted value.

You will find that $a=4$ is false when $a$ is $-4$, but $a^2=16$ is true when $a$ is $-4$. So this is the step where the extraneous solution was introduced.

$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ does not have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

$$(-4) \neq 4$$

$$(-4)^2 = 4^2$$

$x^2$ is not an injective function.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this line of reasoning:

> Suppose $a = 4.$ It follows that $a = 4$ or $a = -4.$

Do you see anything wrong with that line of reasoning?
I hope you do not, because the reasoning is perfectly valid.
It would be very strange to find out that $a=4$ and yet neither 
$a=4$ nor $a = -4$ was true.

Your do not explicitly state how you developed your sequence of equations, but in the absence of explicit language or logical symbols to indicate how the statements relate to each other, we usually take such a sequence of statements to mean that each statement can be justified by the ones that came before it.
Also, we read $a = \pm 4$ as the statement, "$a = 4$ or $a = -4.$"

Given the initial assertion, $a=4,$
it is very simple to justify that $a = 4$ or $a = -4.$
That's what your sequence of statements did.

What you *cannot* do is to use the assumption that $a = 4$ or $a = -4$
to justify a statement that $a=4.$ In other words, you can't just take your sequence of statements and write them down in reverse order, 
starting with $a = \pm 4$ and ending with $a=4.$
That doesn't make sense.
The reason it doesn't work is that $a=4$ is sufficient to show that 
$a^2 = 16,$ but $a^2 = 16$ is not sufficient to show that $a = 4.$

Comment: Sometimes we can get carried away :-)

Answer (score 0):

HINT: we get $$(a)^2=a^2$$ or $$(-a)^2=(-1)^2a^2=a^2$$ the same result.